# Weak convergence exercise.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and let $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $g\in L^1(\mathbb R)$. Suppose that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_n\rightharpoonup f \hbox{ weakly in }L^2(\mathbb R)\,,
\\
f_n^2\rightharpoonup g \hbox{ weakly in }L^1(\mathbb R)\,.
\end{eqnarray*}
Prove that $g\geq f^2$ a.e. in $\mathbb R$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof should make use of the following facts:

1. The $L^2$-norm (in fact, any norm) is lower semicontinuous w.r.t. weak convergence, i.e. $\Vert h \Vert_2 \leq \liminf_n \Vert h_n \Vert_2$ for $h_n \rightharpoonup h$.
2. The map $h \mapsto h \cdot \chi_A$ is continuous (on $L^1$ and on $L^2$).
3. If $h_n \rightharpoonup h$ and $T$ is linear and continuous, then $T h_n \rightharpoonup Th$.
4. You can characterize the inequality $f^2 \leq g$ by using integrals (how?).

EDIT: Here is a more detailed hint. You have (why?)

$$
\int_A |f|^2 = \Vert f \chi_A \Vert_2^2 \leq \liminf_n \Vert f_n \chi_A \Vert_2^2 = \int |f_n|^2 \chi_A.
$$

How does that help you?

Comment: Maybe I'm on a wrong way. I had the same idea, to prove that $\int_A f^2\leq\int_A g$ for all measurable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$. But using the tool you mentioned I can only obtain: $\int_{A}|g|\leq \liminf \int_A f_n^2$ and $\int_{A}f^2\leq \liminf \int_A f_n^2$. I can't see ho to conclude. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: See the edited post. Can you see how to complete the proof? BTW: You should have included your thoughts (in particular the $\int_A f^2 \leq \int_A g$ for all $A$) as part of your question. This helps people trying to answer because (1) They know what you already know, so they do not have to repeat these things, (2) they can give you hints that are suitable to the particular place where you are stuck, (3) it might give them ideas how to proceed.

Comment: Ok, now I got it.

Comment: I have to use that $\chi_A\in L^{\infty}$ and weak convergence in $L^1$ conclude. Right? Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Yes, exactly. More precisely, $\chi_A \in L^\infty \subset (L^1)'$.